# Azure SAS token for container throws 'invalid Signature Size' error

Tags: list, azure, containers, blob

I am trying to list and download blobs from a container on Azure. It works perfectly fine when I try to do so using storage account access key. However, fails when  use a SAS token. I generated the SAS token the with the following PowerShell script:

```
    $storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "myAccount" -StorageAccountKey "<account key>"
$permission = "rwdl"
$sasToken = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken  -Name "myContainer" -Policy "testPolicy" -Context $storageContext >>sastoken.txt
"
```

I get the following result:

```
?sv=2017-04-17&sr=c&si=testPolicy&sig=dbS680%2FXgPp4o%2BQCCzpYzGZszCnDHVjCkdHZRf6KDeg%3D
```

I appended the sas token with resource URI to get:

```
https://myAccount.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer?sv=2017-04-17&sr=c&si=testPolicy&sig=dbS680%2FXgPp4o%2BQCCzpYzGZszCnDHVjCkdHZRf6KDeg%3D
```

and ran the following CLI command:

```
az storage blob list --container-name myContainer --account-name myAccount --auth-mode key --debug --sas-token "https://myAccount.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer?sv=2017-04-17&sr=c&si=testPolicy&sig=dbS680%2FXgPp4o%2BQCCzpYzGZszCnDHVjCkdHZRf6KDeg%3D" >> bloblist.txt
```

I get the following error:

> azure.multiapi.storage.v2018_03_28.common.storageclient :
>   Client-Request-ID=0f7a 7762-3729-11e9-8b32-ffc4c9592d0a Retry policy
>   did not allow for a retry: Server- Timestamp=Sat, 23 Feb 2019 05:08:30
>   GMT, Server-Request-ID=21f07a6a-f01e-00e9-32 35-cb7d5c000000, HTTP
>   status code=403, Exception=Server failed to authenticate t he request.
>   Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly incl
>   uding the signature. ErrorCode: AuthenticationFailed`AuthenticationFailed`Server failed to auth enticate the request. Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed corr ectly including the
>   signature.RequestId:21f07a6a-f01e-00e9-3235-cb7d5c000000Time
>   :2019-02-23T05:08:30.7149353Z**Signature
>   size  is invalid**.

You do not have the required permissions needed to perform this operation.
Depending on your operation, you may need to be assigned one of the following ro
les:

```
"Storage Blob Data Contributor (Preview)"
"Storage Blob Data Reader (Preview)"
"Storage Queue Data Contributor (Preview)"
"Storage Queue Data Reader (Preview)"
```

If you want to use the old authentication method and allow querying for the righ
t account key, please use the "--auth-mode" parameter and "key" value.

> Event: CommandInvoker.OnFilterResult [] 'CommandResultItem' object is
>   not iterable Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r8nye8gm\knack\knack\cl
>   i.py", line 212, in invoke   File
>   "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r8nye8gm\knack\knack\ou
>   tput.py", line 132, in out   File
>   "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r8nye8gm\knack\knack\ou
>   tput.py", line 38, in format_json TypeError: 'CommandResultItem'
>   object is not iterable telemetry.save : Save telemetry record of
>   length 2499 in cache

I have tried generating a storage account level SAS portal, but didnt find any luck.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're using full SAS URL instead of SAS token.

Please change the following:

```
az storage blob list --container-name myContainer --account-name myAccount --auth-mode key --debug --sas-token "https://myAccount.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer?sv=2017-04-17&sr=c&si=testPolicy&sig=dbS680%2FXgPp4o%2BQCCzpYzGZszCnDHVjCkdHZRf6KDeg%3D" >> bloblist.txt
```

to

```
az storage blob list --container-name myContainer --account-name myAccount --auth-mode key --debug --sas-token "?sv=2017-04-17&sr=c&si=testPolicy&sig=dbS680%2FXgPp4o%2BQCCzpYzGZszCnDHVjCkdHZRf6KDeg%3D" >> bloblist.txt
```

And you should be able to list blobs.

Comment: thanks @Gaurav Mantri, this works fine when I run the command from the cli. However, It throws the same error when I copy the command in a bat file and call it from a python script. do you know what must be causing it?

Comment: Please ask a separate question for this. Make sure to include “python” tag in your question.

Answer (score 22):

For anyone else that comes along with the same azcopy error with `403 AuthenticationFailed` but the detail shows `Signature size is invalid` - I had the same problem when trying to script azcopy from a windows .bat file. When you get the SAS url, there will be percent signs in the string. You must double up the percent signs to ***"escape"*** them when running from a .bat file. e.g. **wherever you see a % in the url, make it %%** - hope this helps!

Funny thing is I remembered to do this in the first 3 azcopy scripts I wrote and a few weeks later made a 4th one for a new storage account and couldn't figure out why i kept getting 403. I suppose this post will be a reminder to myself the next time I forget again :)

Comment: You are my hero. 

Comment: could have spent easily few more hours stuck on that. many tanks